# Backing up directories with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, backup

I have a function in my .bashrc that I use to backup files:

```
backup() {
    filename=`date +F-%H-%M`-"$@"
    /bin/cp -fr "$@" ~/backup/$filename
}
```

and I would like to make an alias to easily backup a project in the folder foxhound:

```
alias backfox="backup /home/projects/Foxhound"
```

I get the error

```
/bin/cp: cannot create directory `/home/username/backup/2012-01-23-15-03-/home/projects/Foxhound`: No such file or directory
```

Comment: you might consider using rsync instead of cp for backups; it's much more efficient. Here's a quick tutorial http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/#Rsync

Comment: Take it from @TJD , rsync is what you want to use.

Comment: Cool.  I eventually changed this to an rsync call and it was much easier.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to add:

```
mkdir -p $filename
```

before the `cp` line.

Comment: I do however agree with the comments to your questions. Use rsync ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I usually tar/zip the directory with something like this

```
tar -czf backup-$(date +-%Y-%m%d-%H%Mh%S).tar.gz $filename
```

then just `mv` the tar to the backups directory/file server etc.

It makes it easier than dealing a bunch of directories